# Confluent replicator issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to push topic data from one Kafka cluster to another (Both on-prem linux). For this, I am using Confluent kafka-connect-replicator.

Using - confluent enterprise 5.0

Following this doc -
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-replicator/index.html#replicator-as-a-connector

I have already changed ports of zookeeper and broker to 2171 and 9082 resp. at source Kafka cluster.
Destination Kafka cluster is running on default ports.

My configuration files are :

```
/etc/kafka-connect-replicator/quickstart-replicator.properties

name=replicator-source
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter
header.converter=io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter

tasks.max=4

src.kafka.bootstrap.servers=X.X.X.X:9082
src.zookeeper.connect=X.X.X.X:2171

dest.kafka.bootstrap.servers=Y.Y.Y.Y:9092
dest.zookeeper.connect=Y.Y.Y.Y:2181

confluent.topic.replication.factor=1

topic.whitelist=test-topic
topic.rename.format=${topic}.replica    
topic.create.backoff.ms=10000
```

/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9082
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/data/kafka/connect.offsets
plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

Run the replicator connector -

```
/usr/bin/connect-standalone /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties /etc/kafka-connect-replicator/quickstart-replicator.properties
```

But when I run the replicator, it creates replica topic at destination cluster but if I produce messages, it doesn't show in the consumer at the destination cluster. 
It also throws WARNs at the command prompt.

```
Nov 28, 2018 2:22:26 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource will be ignored.
Nov 28, 2018 2:22:26 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource will be ignored.
Nov 28, 2018 2:22:26 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkProviderRuntime
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource will be ignored.
Nov 28, 2018 2:22:26 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains empty path annotation.
```

connect.log

```
[2018-11-28 14:29:58,849] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=replicator-source-3} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:397)
[2018-11-28 14:29:58,849] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=replicator-source-3} flushing 1 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:414)
[2018-11-28 14:30:03,850] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=replicator-source-3} Failed to flush, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 1 messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:419)
[2018-11-28 14:30:03,850] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=replicator-source-3} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter:111)
```

[image]

What am I missing? How can I replicate data to the other cluster broker?

thanks!

Comment: In the consumer command that you run to confirm that messages are copied, have you added the flag `--from-beginning`? If replicator copies the message before you run the consumer, you won't see the record in the consumer without this flag. The `ERROR` message is not critical if you don't keep seeing it after some time. It's common for Replicator to fail committing all the offsets while catching up with replication, but eventually it does. Normally, you'll see the number of outstanding messages being reduced.

Comment: I keep getting this error also-
[2018-11-28 17:37:20,563] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=replicator-source-3} Failed to flush, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 1 messages (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:419)
[2018-11-28 17:37:20,563] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=replicator-source-3} Failed to commit offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceTaskOffsetCommitter:111)

Comment: I notice your configuration has "test-topic" but your producer and consumer are calling "testing-topic". I'm guessing this is just a typo but seemed worth mentioning.